# Azure Data Flows isolate-find substrings form text field

Tags: azure, data-manipulation, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I am trying to isolate several substrings from a specific column of a parquet file that contains text (string). The substrings are all in an array and I want to keep only those rows that contain one or more of these substrings - words, while I keep a new column with the substrings that where found at the text.

I have currently used the following transformations:

1. source: which is the parquet file I use
2. derived column: where I create a new column (words) which contains an array of the words-substrings that are contained in the text, by using the following expression
   **intersect(split(text_column, ' '), ['array','of','words'])**
3. filter: where I want to filter the derived column that was created at the previous transformation and exclude those rows that are either Null or contain an empty array
4. sink

I have currently stuck to the 3rd transformation where I cannot filter and discard those rows that the 2 arrays do not intersect. I think that when intersect doesn't find any common element it returns an empty string array which I have not find the right condition that filters it out.
I have tried:
**1. not(isNull(words))
2. word != array('')
3. not(isNull(word[1]))**
but none of them worked.

Any suggestions regarding the whole process or the filtering of the empty string array will be perfect.
Thank you in advance.

I was expecting to get back only the rows that contain at least one of the substrings, but I get all the rows regardless if they contain one of the substrings.

Comment: In filter transformation, give condition as `size(words)!=0`

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of the array and remove the rows with array size=0. In filter transformation, filter on  `size(words)!=0`.

- I repro'd this with sample inputs.  [image]
- Derived column transformation with same expression is given.
  `intersect(split(text_column, ' '), ['array','of','words'])`

[image]

- Then in Filter transformation, condition is given as filter on `size(words)!=0`

[image]

By this way, we can remove the empty array.

**Reference:** [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#size) on size expression.